# How to set an alarm in cloud watch and send notification ,if SQS message not deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I Need to set an alarm ,if SQS Queue message has not deleted in hour and need to send notification .

I have tried based on cloud watch metric ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage  ,but unble to get the timer.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to do? What does it mean "but unble to get the timer"? What timer? Get how?

Comment: It's working based on metric ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage,  I can able to send notification if the message is older than hour